# How do I use mongo aggregation to lookup data in a subdocument?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to `$lookup` data from a subdocument in another collection. I have survey answers, and I want to group them by the question category's name.

The survey documents looks like this:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("62555be60401f0a21553da9a"),
  name: 'new survey',
  questions: [
    {
      text: 'question 1',
      category_id: new ObjectId("62555be60401f0a21553da99"),
      options: [Array],
      _id: new ObjectId("62555be60401f0a21553da9c"),
    },
    ...
}
```

Category collection is just name and _id:

```
{
   _id: new ObjectId("62555be60401r0a27553da99"),
   name: "category name"
}
```

I have answer data like this:

```
[
  {
    answers: {
      k: '62555be60401f0a21553da9c',
      v: new ObjectId("62555880da8fb89651f6a292")
    },
  },
  {
    answers: {
      k: '62555880da8fb89651f6a29b',
      v: new ObjectId("62555880da8fb89651f6a29e")
    },
  }
  ...
]
```

`k` is a string that matches to the `_id` in the `survey.questions` array.

I'd like to get the resulting data like this:

```
[
  {
    answers: {
      k: 'question 1',
      v: new ObjectId("62555880da8fb89651f6a292")
    },
    category: 'category name'
  },
  {
    answers: {
      k: 'question 2',
      v: new ObjectId("62555880da8fb89651f6a29e")
    },
    category: 'other category name'
  }
  ...
]
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

I think I could probably figure out the category part, but I cannot figure out how to use `$lookup` to get info from a subdocument. From the docs I'm guessing its maybe some pipeline within a lookup. Pretty stumped though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, using a pipeline to match only `surveys` that have `questions._id` that matches the `answer.k` value

```
db.answer.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      "from": "survey",
      "let": {
        "k": {
          "$toObjectId": "$answers.k"
        }
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {"$in": ["$$k", "$questions._id"]}
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "details"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      answers: 1,
      details: {"$arrayElemAt": ["$details", 0]}
      }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      answers: 1,
      categoryData: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$details.questions",
          as: "item",
          cond: {$eq: ["$$item._id", {"$toObjectId": "$answers.k"}]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      answers: 1,
      catData: {"$arrayElemAt": ["$categoryData", 0]}
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Category",
      localField: "catData.category_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "cat"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      answers: 1,
      _id: 0,
      category: {"$arrayElemAt": ["$cat", 0]}
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {answers: 1, name: "$category.name"}
  }
])
```

As you can see on the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/r2AhpQucdq3)

Maybe it is possible to filter the results during the `$lookup` in order to simplify the rest of the query

Comment: Is it working for you?